# ffmpeg how to extract audio from mkv to ogg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

ffmpeg how to extract audio from mkv to ogg. My mkv file have 2 audio track. I use this command.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -vn -acodec copy audio.ogg
```

It show error like this.

```
[ogg @ 00000186dcba1040] Unsupported codec id in stream 0
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

How to extract audio from mkv to ogg.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i test.mkv -vn audio.ogg`

Comment: See [A quick guide to using FFmpeg to convert media files | Opensource.com](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/ffmpeg-convert-media-file-formats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

> ffmpeg -y -v error -stats -i test.mkv -vn   -map 0:a:0 -acodec copy
> audio1.ogg -map 0:a:1 -acodec copy audio2.ogg

if still not working remove  `-acodec copy`